# Using conditional to Update OR Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dml

I have written a stored procedure that updates a table and then writes old records to a historical table, using `OUTPUT deleted.*`

I am now looking to update the procedure and include an @option parameter, which will be either 1 or 2. If the option is 1, the records will be updated in the target table. If it is 2, then they will be deleted from the table.

Is there any way to write in a conditional that will update or insert based on this input parameter? I can write it as

```
IF @option = 1
BEGIN
  ...updates...
END

IF @option = 2
BEGIN
  ...deletes...
END
```

but there are many fields being updated/deleted and the process repeats three more times, so I am trying to make it more concise.

I have tried doing `(CASE @option WHEN 1 THEN UPDATE WHEN 2 THEN DELETE) table1 ...` but that is incorrect SQL. I have considered using `MERGE` and including the conditional, something like `WHEN MATCHED AND @option = 1 THEN` but am getting syntax errors there. I am also not too familiar with `MERGE` so if anybody has any insight into this process, it would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify, my question is:

Is there any way to conditionally `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (or do other DML operations)?

Comment: I know it sounds picky but you don't delete fields, you delete records. If you want to make a field have no value, you update it to a NULL. It is important because conceptually you could need multiple updates in one if block and then only one delete in the delete IF block. So unless you want to update all fields if one of them changes, you really shouldn't consider using merge (Not a fan anyway, it is buggy and very hard to troubleshoot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MERGE` works by inserting records that don't exist and updating those that do, which is a common scenario.  Even so it's not much more concise than separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, since you still have to supply the statements separately (just wrapped inside a single `MERGE` statement.

Conditionally updating or deleting is not a common scenario in my experience, so there's not a concise SQL syntax to do so.

I would note that fields aren't specified in a `DELETE` so there is some difference in the syntax anyways.  I think having an `if` block that separates the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` is going to be as concise as you can get.

Comment: I wrote it out using the two IF's and there is really not much space that can be saved. Thanks for the explanation